# How to check map array in unit test flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-test

I want to test map array in unit test to auto generate data
if I give parameter with map array and give data for that param, data want to return null or empty string at json with one function
How can I write that

thanks

Comment: I'm having some difficulties understanding the question. Could you explain this differently?

Comment: thanks @dumazy  I want to check map array in unit test (for eg.  if if will give parameter like id= null , name = 'data'  the given parameter want to return auto generate to json)